# Community Cloud without other Cloud

Tags: community, licenses, community-cloud

I'm little bit confused with the architecture of Community Cloud. Till now i have worked with community cloud in addition with another clouds as Sales Cloud.

I have a question... Can i build an org only with community cloud? It means, without Sales, Service or Platform licenses, or should i create communities through another cloud?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Comment: You still need full Salesforce licences for your adminstrators or any integrations, but you could have a community with only Customer Community and Company Community users, however I think that it would be too limiting for the internal users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a Community off the Force.com platform license. See your Account Representative for more on your options.

It really depends on what you want to do and what features you desire. There are a great number of Community license types including the HVCP and other licenses. Which one to use greatly depends on the objects you want to access. Recognize that if you want access to objects like Opportunity, you'd need to have an org that uses the Salesforce.com license where a Force.com org does not. This is why you need to contact your Account Representative to discuss your specific needs.